# symmetric and orthogonal matrices are connected?

Tags: general-topology

Are the set of all symmetric matrices and orthogonal matrcises connected in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $M_n(\mathbb{C})$?completely out of idea.plz help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the images of each set under the determinant map. Are either of the images connected?

Comment: aha! in that case  $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ is not connected but Symmetric  matrices can have det value any real number so they are connected

Comment: Note that the preimage of a connected set under continuous function might be disconnected. So you can only argue a set being $not$-connected if its continuous image is $not$-connected.

Comment: ok I am feeling that Symm matrices are path connected?

Comment: @Makuasi sure just show there's a path between every symmetric matrix and the 0 matrix.

Comment: @jacob, every vector space is path connected, so are syymm matrces....

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the set of all real symmetric matrix is a convex set. So, obviously path connected